# C++ library for digital signal modulations like QPSK/16QAM/64QAM/BPSK/PSK

Tags: open-source, library, c++, signal-processing

I have found interesting C++ library that shares basic digital signal processing operations: https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters

Is there any C++ library that contains modulations like QPSK/16QAM/64QAM/BPSK/PSK?